# Performance of big network graphs in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, igraph, networkd3, visnetwork

I have a graph with like 250 nodes and 350 edges. I want to visualize the graph using networkD3 or visNetwork. However, both of those solutions are very slow.

forcenetwork almost crashes my browser. I want to use this visualization in a Shiny app. Is there a way to make js graph that will be reasonably fast, or is my graph simply too big?